# WPF WebBrowser and CSS3 linear-gradient is it possible?

Tags: c#, css, wpf, webbrowser-control, gradient

Trying to use `background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);` in css for WebBrowser control but it doesn't work is it possible to achieve gradient effect for html element in this control?

PS I need to do it for html which is passed into the control using NavigateToString

Comment: It seems there is no reliable way to do so. Only workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least in .net framework 4.5.2 it is impossible to do so without any hacks so I am unable to do it in production for WPF desktop app

Answer (score 2):

The WebBrowser control is just a wrapper around IE. If it is supported in IE then it is supported on the WebBrowser control.

However, the IE version that runs inside the control depends on a registry setting. You can force the WebBrowser to use a certain version by editing the registry. The following would force the control to use IE 9

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (or HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
   SOFTWARE
      Microsoft
         Internet Explorer
            Main
               FeatureControl
                  FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
                     yourexename.exe = (DWORD) 00009000
```

The values for different IE versions as well as more information on the WebBrowser control emulation mode can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Furthermore, gradients are one of those things that differ greatly between browsers, I believe that the syntax for IE 6-9's gradient is

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='red', endColorstr='yellow',GradientType=0 );
```

Comment: It is a bad option because the application runs on the customer's PCs. At the moment the best workaround I found is to store a line with gradient as a picture and use it as a background in html.